# Apple Match-O Linker Error library not found Xcode 6.4

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6

I am trying to test my app and I did duplicate 'Debug' on configurations to 'Debug_Test' to change the environment. I use macro to change the source code.

I have added Preprocessor Macros to 'Debug_test', and change 'Run' and 'Test' schemas to 'Debug_Test'.
I have tested it,but I got the error mentioned below.

```
Ld /Users/Kuma/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestClient-arjbprptvrrztsesaxtkhhsypwyc/Build/Products/Debug_Test-iphonesimulator/ShareEx.appex/ShareEx normal x86_64
cd /Users/Kuma/Desktop/Test/TestClient
export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=8.4
export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.4.sdk -L/Users/Kuma/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestClient-arjbprptvrrztsesaxtkhhsypwyc/Build/Products/Debug_Test-iphonesimulator -F/Users/Kuma/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestClient-arjbprptvrrztsesaxtkhhsypwyc/Build/Products/Debug_Test-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/Kuma/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestClient-arjbprptvrrztsesaxtkhhsypwyc/Build/Intermediates/TestClient.build/Debug_Test-iphonesimulator/ShareEx.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ShareEx.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/../../Frameworks -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -ObjC -lAFNetworking -framework CoreGraphics -framework MobileCoreServices -framework Security -framework SystemConfiguration /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.4.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PlugInKit.framework/PlugInKit -e _NSExtensionMain -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -fapplication-extension -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=8.4 -Xlinker -sectcreate -Xlinker __TEXT -Xlinker __entitlements -Xlinker /Users/Kuma/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestClient-arjbprptvrrztsesaxtkhhsypwyc/Build/Intermediates/TestClient.build/Debug_Test-iphonesimulator/ShareEx.build/ShareEx.appex.xcent -framework ShareExtensionEmbedded -lPods-ShareEx -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/Kuma/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestClient-arjbprptvrrztsesaxtkhhsypwyc/Build/Intermediates/TestClient.build/Debug_Test-iphonesimulator/ShareEx.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/ShareEx_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/Kuma/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TestClient-arjbprptvrrztsesaxtkhhsypwyc/Build/Products/Debug_Test-iphonesimulator/ShareEx.appex/ShareEx

ld: library not found for -lAFNetworking
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Of course, before change the schemas, I can build and I added AFNetworking to my AppExtension.
I think other settings are needed. But, I am beginner and do not know settings.

If anyone know the solution, please tell me.

Comment: I use cocoapods to install AFNetworking. I also think that pods make issue of this problem.

Comment: I have updated my answer may be it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

**First**, please ensure to add `AFNetworking` library in your target's `Build Phase` tab. If its already there, please remove and re-add.

[image]

**Second**, ensure your `Library Search Path` is set correctly:

[image]

Comment: But, I can not build yet. I do first thing. But, I do not know what is correct path. I look at "Library Search Paths" of my app extension, and I find the Library Search Paths show $(inherited) and $(PROJECT_DIR)/build/Debug-iphoneos. I delete $(PROJECT_DIR)/build/Debug-iphoneos and run test, but build is failed. When I also set $(PROJECT_DIR)/build/Debug_Test-iphoneos, build is failed and show" ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/Kuma/Desktop/Test/TestClient/build/Debug_Test-iphoneos'". If you have any points, please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the same problem with the following code.

Add this to the Library Search Paths in Build Settings and make sure you select recursive, delete other library paths which might be absolute paths.

```
$(PROJECT_DIR)
```

May be it will help you.